# get users that did not buy a product

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables

`users` table

```
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id                       | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| AccountNumber            | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| DisplayName              | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ParentAccountId          | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| AccountTypeRef           | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PhoneNo                  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| FaxNo                    | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Website                  | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Email                    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| StateRef                 | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| Address                  | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| PostalCode               | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

`products` table

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id                | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ProductId         | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| PackName          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |               |
| Price             | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| OnlineInfoAddress | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Description       | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| IsDelete          | tinyint      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CreateUserId      | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CreateDate        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EditDate          | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| EditUserId        | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Tag               | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Ref               | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| deleted_at        | timestamp    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`users_buy` table

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id            | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| users_id      | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| product_id    | bigint       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| BuyDate       | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| CountBuy      | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| TotalPrice    | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Description   | longtext     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| invoiceNumber | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**I want to get users who did not buy a specific product**

for example, user number 20 bought 5 product with ids [1,2,3,4,5]
and user number 19 bought 3 product with ids [1,2,3]

And user number 18 bought 2 product with ids [1,3]

I want to get users who did not buy any product with the id 5

ie I want user 18 and 19

How can I do this?

Comment: you provided table metadata, but no sample. Could you provide some sample data for all the three tables (preferably in csv)?

Comment: Your question is almost formed nicely but instead of posting the entire structure if you could provide the DDL script and the sample data in SQL format would be nice. You have to show your attempt as well and expected result in tabular text format.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will list of all users that did not buy product id 5:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE
Id NOT IN (
    SELECT users_id
    FROM users_buy
    WHERE product_id = 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution used LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT users.* 
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users_buy 
    ON users_buy.users_id = users.id AND users_buy.product_id = 5
WHERE users_buy.user_id IS NULL;
```

The above query will return records from users table have not matched rows in users_buy table with product_id 5